# Existe alguna manera de obtener el valor de los onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

Es decir quisiera obtener el valor de los `onclick="ejemplo"` obtener la función del onclick

Comment: puedes tratar de explicar mejor lo que quieres

Comment: Buenas, por favor, revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: si tengo un onclick="ejemplo();", quisiera si existe la manera de obtener esa function "ejemplo();"

Comment: A que te refieres con "obtener la función del onclick", quieres obtener el valor que retorna la función?

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con getAttribute:

```
var x = document.querySelector("button").getAttribute("onclick");
```

Ejemplo: https://codepen.io/bitxelus/pen/MozpQR

Comment: Aqui cada uno hemos entendido algo diferente xD, espero que aclare un poco para concretar mas nuestras respuestas.

Comment: Sip, no se entiende la pregunta :/, veremos...

Answer (score 0):

Usa `HTML` de jquery si quieres sacar lo escrito dentro de un div por ejemplo. Tienes otras opciones, dependiento a que te refieras con valor, como `val()`

```js
var valor=$('#b').html();

function alertar(){
alert(valor);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="b" onclick="alertar()">ESTO ES UN DIV</div>
```